# Media Module Bulk Upload for Image Field

Tags: 7, media

Using [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) 7.x-2.x-version I am trying to use the integrated Bulk Upload Module. I have activated Media Bulk Upload sub module as part of Media. Now if I use a image field with media selector I can still upload only one image at a time. Only if I go to "file/add" I have the multiple file upload option. Is this by design or is there a possibilty to use multiple file upload directly when adding content via Image field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also faced the same issue. But after applying this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/951004) (check your media module version) it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Content types -> Manage fields and edit the image field. select "Number of values" as "unlimited" and save. This allows you to add multiple files.

Comment: Yes I know about the unlimited number of values and have set the field like this, but unfortunately it is not possible to bulk upload more than one image at a time, while the same is possible via "file/add". This means I can attach multiple images but need to upload each one separately while I was hoping to be able to bulk upload them.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution to conveniently bulk upload a number of images directly in a node with the Media Bulk Upload feature. Media Bulk Upload allows me to bulk upload images to the files library (add/files). But if I want to include them in a multiple value image field in a node, I have to add each image separately from the Media library.

So I ended up using [Block Upload module](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_upload). I create the node first without images and then I bulk upload as many images as I like in one step to the image field with the Block Upload module. That's really a great time saver.

Actually there is a issue with the bulk upload form of the module, but the issue can be fixed easily, [look here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2434019)